# Value for undefined key but it is defined (Core Data)?

Tags: swift, core-data

I have the following function that would remove from the "Map" entity (that has 'name' as the only attribute) the specified 'mapname', in this case 'peachfarm'.

However, I get the error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key peachfarm.'

```
func deleteMap(_ sender: UIButton) {
    var mapname = sender.accessibilityHint
    managedObjectContext.delete(fetchedResultsControllerForMapEntity.value(forKey: mapname!) as! NSManagedObject)
}
```

This is weird because I definitely have a value for the above key.

Comment: Calling `someEntity.value(forKey: mapName)` makes no sense. You have to fetch the matching objects before you can delete them. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38017449/swift-3-core-data-delete-object for an example.