# How to delete a tableview index.row from data core swift 4

Tags: swift, core-data

I have created an entity called Medications and the function for adding new data is :

```
@objc func saveUserSettings() {

    SVProgressHUD.show()

    let name = medicationNameTextField.text
    let dosage = dosageTextField.text
    let frequency = medicationNameTextField.text
    let reminder = dosageTextField.text

    let medication = Medications(context: PersistenceService.context)
    medication.name = name
    medication.dosage = dosage
    medication.frequency = frequency
    medication.reminder = reminder

    PersistenceService.saveContext()
    self.meds.append(medication)

}
```

How can I delete one of those indexes  when pressing the delete button at the table view cell?

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    if editingStyle == .delete {

        meds.remove(at: indexPath.row)

        let task = meds[indexPath.row]

        PersistenceService.saveContext()

        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }        

}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Don't use `self.tableView.reloadData()`in this case. Use `self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)` to get the nice cell animation.

Answer (score 2):

Deleteing from the array here

```
meds.remove(at: indexPath.row)
```

doesn't automatically remove it from coreData , you need to use

```
context.delete(object)
```

before saving the context see here   [Swift 3 Core Data Delete Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38017449/swift-3-core-data-delete-object)

Also do it in correct order

```
let task = meds[indexPath.row]

context.delete(task) // access context anywhere but this statement should run

PersistenceService.saveContext()

meds.remove(at: indexPath.row)
```

Comment: What the object would be? Didn't understand the (object)