# My Xcode App crashes after trying to implement NSFetchedResultsController due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException'

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, crash, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I recently asked a question on how to implement a delete function for my CoreData entities. (here:[How do I delete CoreData entries in a tableview that uses a persistentcontainer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56642709/how-do-i-delete-coredata-entries-in-a-tableview-that-uses-a-persistentcontainer)) I was informed that I should make use of the NSFetchResultsController so I began to work on that. I thought I got it right my code now crashes immediately after running.

I have tried using a tutorial to implement the FetchedResultsController. I am pretty sure I have followed all the steps correctly to implement into my app but it still crashes. My attempt is provided below. My original code which works is in the paragraph above.

**ViewController.swift**

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class ViewController: UITableViewController {

    //var alarmItems: [NSManagedObject] = []
    let cellId = "cellId"

    private let persistentContainer = NSPersistentContainer(name: "AlarmItems")

    fileprivate lazy var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController<AlarmItems> = {
        //create fetch request
        let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<AlarmItems> = AlarmItems.fetchRequest()

        //configure fetch request
        //fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: )]

        let fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: self.persistentContainer.viewContext, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)

        fetchedResultsController.delegate = self as? NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate

        return fetchedResultsController
    }()


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        //guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else { return }
        //let managedContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
        //let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSManagedObject>(entityName: "AlarmItems")
        do {
            //alarmItems = try managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
            try fetchedResultsController.performFetch()
        } catch let err as NSError {
            print("Failed to fetch items", err)
        }
    }

    @objc func addAlarmItem(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        //print("this works")
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Add New Item", message: "Please fill in the blanks", preferredStyle: .alert)
        let saveAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Save", style: .default) { [unowned self] action in

            //combined string of attributes
            let myStrings: [String] = alertController.textFields!.compactMap { $0.text }
            let myText = myStrings.joined(separator: ", ")

            self.save(myText)
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .destructive, handler: nil)

        alertController.addTextField { (textField) in
            textField.placeholder = "Enter Name of Engineer"
        }
        alertController.addTextField { (textField) in
            textField.placeholder = "Enter Date of Alarm in DD/MM/YYYY"
        }
        alertController.addTextField { (textField) in
            textField.placeholder = "Enter Time of Alarm in 24h (eg: 2300)"
        }
        alertController.addTextField { (textField) in
            textField.placeholder = "Please indicate True/False (type True or False)"
        }
        alertController.addTextField { (textField) in
            textField.placeholder = "Insert comments (if any), or NIL"
        }


        alertController.addAction(saveAction)
        alertController.addAction(cancelAction)
        present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func save(_ itemName: String) {
        guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else { return }
        let managedContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
        let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "AlarmItems", in: managedContext)!
        let item = NSManagedObject(entity: entity, insertInto: managedContext)
        item.setValue(itemName, forKey: "alarmAttributes")


        do {
            try managedContext.save()
            //NSFetchedResultsController.append(item)
            tableView.reloadData()

        } catch let err as NSError {
            print("Failed to save an item", err)
        }
    }

    @objc func exportCSV(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        //will work on exporting csv in the future
        return
    }
    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return fetchedResultsController.sections?.count ?? 0
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{
        //return alarmItems.count
        let sectionInfo = fetchedResultsController.sections![section]
        return sectionInfo.numberOfObjects
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath)
        let alarmItem = fetchedResultsController.object(at: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = alarmItem.value(forKeyPath: "alarmAttributes") as? String
        return cell
    }


}
```

- The error is:

  > Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'An instance of NSFetchedResultsController requires a non-nil fetchRequest and managedObjectContext'

They also say that it failed to load the model named AlarmItems even though I already have the fetch request function in my code.

Comment: Try adding exception breakpoints to see where your code is going wrong. It'll give you an idea where you need to check your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all delete `let persistentContainer = NSPersistentContainer(name: "AlarmItems")` and get the context from `AppDelegate`

The error is incomplete

> An instance of NSFetchedResultsController requires a non-nil fetchRequest **with sort descriptors** and managedObjectContext

```
fileprivate lazy var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController<AlarmItems> = {
    //create fetch request
    let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<AlarmItems> = AlarmItems.fetchRequest()

    //configure fetch request
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "alarmAttributes", ascending: true)]
    let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext

    let fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: context, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)

    fetchedResultsController.delegate = self

    return fetchedResultsController
}()
```

And as already mentioned please name the `NSManagedObject` subclass in singular form `AlarmItem`

Comment: thank you so much for your help the past few days :) i really appreciate it. I will try that and hopefully things will be okay